# When I switch from IIS Express to IIS with fully qualified name. There is this jquery error happening. Why?

Tags: ajax, jquery, iis

I THINK it is related to the ajax calls on the client side.. Any ideas? Works fine in IIS Express `(http://localhost:7000)`

This is the line the error occurs on in the jquery-2.0.0.js:

xhr.open( options.type, options.url, options.async, options.username, options.password );

and the error is:

Exception was thrown at line 7713, column 5 in http://processmanager.something.us.magepub.org/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js

0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

Comment: Open your browser's debugger. Go to the NET tab. Look for errors. It's probably a path problem.

Comment: What is the path you are using in your Ajax call (I assume it doesn't have port 7000 specified on it as shown above; unless you configured the site on IIS to work on port 7000)? Depending on how you deployed it to IIS it _could_ be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. I was dumb and was calling localhost and forgot about it when I moved to IIS

```
 $.getJSON("http://localhost:7000/api/WAPIHome/" + SelectedTaskValue, function (data) {
```